# Can not run console on Heroku, or run any commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm unable to connect to Heroku's console as I could in the past using:

```
$ heroku run rails console
```

The result of that is:

```
Running `rails console` attached to terminal... up, run.4695
!    
!    Timeout awaiting process
```

Following a Heroku [guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#troubleshooting), I issued this command..

```
$ telnet rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com 5000
```

and the result was:

```
Trying 50.19.103.36...
telnet: connect to address 50.19.103.36: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

I switched to another ISP recently, and I have verified with their tech support that they don't block access to any ports (including 5000). So, I really don't know what's going on.

What else can I do? I sincerely need help.

Thanks in advance,

Kind Regards,

Comment: did you try `heroku run console`?

Comment: @phoet Yes, indeed I did try that option as well sir. :( Same result. Any ideas? (I will to call Heroku tech support), do you know If someone from Heroku maybe keeps an eye for questions like this in StackOverflow? -Thank you for your reply.